# Ruby and Sinatra: where does this extra string come from and how to eliminate it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Part of the code in "routes.rb",

```
...
post '/csr' do
  text = PkiSupport::display_csr('/etc/pki/subordinate_ca.csr')
  erb :download_csr, :locals => { :csr => text }
end
```

In "PkiSupport.rb"

```
...
def display_csr(csr_file)
  text = `more #{csr_file}`
  return text
end
```

In "download_csr.erb"

```
...
<form id="csr-form" action="<%= url "/subordinate_ca/csr" %>" method="post">
  <h4>csr</h4>
  <textarea cols="80" rows="36" name="csr">
    <%= csr %>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

The idea is very simple, when user chooses "/csr", shell command "more ..." will be executed and the output string shown in the textarea of a form.

It does show up correctly, but contains extra preceding string (below), which is anything ahead of "-----BEGIN...". So how to prevent it?

```
      ::::::::::::::
/etc/pki/subordinate_ca.csr
::::::::::::::
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIFATCCAukCAQAwaDETMBEGCgmSJomT8ixkARkWA2NvbTETMBEGCgmSJomT8ixk
ARkWA3h5ejEQMA4GA1UECgwHWFlaIEluYzESMBAGA1UECwwJTWFya2V0aW5nMRYw
FAYDVQQDDA0xMC4xMC4xMzAuMTU4MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIIC
CgKCAgEAruWYRn7mjZkHeD+PPLpMSBRoYnLKNvYMte9XneFDh1TItLolYhM4bmWX
gewKOO9+kNY21CoVu1jYZ3q9WitgJlS3tMHPhc6IjuY9DfQ58aeJaZHO8+ISE3Op
l6xNcaxOeHXMlVgdeX4ouyzB2ykJVhu1KtE+XTKilUu6nIrH6ETHrxelBs36Hu1q
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the string do you consider as extra?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but... any specific reason why you're using `more #{file}`? Wouldn't `cat #{file}` be better? And better still, `File.read(file)`? Also - why not try logging your strings to see what they are before you dump them to the web page, to see exactly what they are at each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your culprit line of code is this one:

```
text = `more #{csr_file}`
```

That code forks and runs the standard Unix `more` program. Some versions of `more` will detect if they're run from another program, and output things slightly differently. That's what you're seeing here.

The quickest fix would be to change that line to

```
text = `cat #{csr_file}`
```

`cat` doesn't try to be as smart as `more` and will give you just the contents of the file.

Now, that said, there's no reason why your Ruby program needs to run a separate program just to read the contents of a file - Ruby has support for reading files directly. So the best fix would be to change that line to:

```
text = File.read(csr_file)
```

That will be faster and more portable.

Comment: Be very careful of "slurping" data using `read`. Trying to read a file larger then the available memory will take the code, and machine, to its knees. [`File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is very fast, and can avoid that problem completely.

Comment: It works when using "File.read", thanks. I think buffer overflow shouldn't be a big problem here because it is a standard csr file.